# больше одного условия if

Tags: python, if

Попробую объяснить, это для меня новое.
Мой код:

```
if first condition..:
    ...
    a = b * c
    ...  
if sec condition..: 
    d = a * e
```

Этот код не работает, так как в последней строке a is not defined. Эта функция как бы существует только внутри первого условия, так? Мне нужно использовать а далее, в при выполненном втором условии.

Я не использую else вместо if sec condition, потому что условия там не обратные друг другу, они просто разные.

Вот так тоже не выходит:

```
if first condition..:
    a = b * c
    ...  
    if sec condition..: 
        d = a * e
```

потому что после выполнения задачи под первым условием, оно меняется и first condition больше не true и код не доходит до sec condition.

Короче, как использовать функцию из первого условия далее в коде? Это возможно? Или  весь код далее нужно строить под первым условием if?

Comment: А если а объявить перед первым условием?

Comment: Не, вкратце, а зависит от  первого условия

Comment: Всё будет работать, если `first condition` сработает

Comment: Если `first condition` истинно, то `a = b * c`, а если ложно, то чему должно быть равно `a`?

Comment: Можешь дать более понятное описание того что ты хочешь сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может в другом ошибка, только что проверял python 3.5.2 | 2.7.12, запустил тест все работает

```
if True:
    a = 'aaa'
    if True:
        b = 'bbb'
    print(b)  # bbb
    del b 
    print(b)  # NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Присоединяюсь к последнему комментарию, если условие отработает все будет нормально, тогда нужен `try`, `except`

```
if True:
    a = 'aaa'
    if True:
        b = 'bbb'
    try:
        print(b)  # bbb
        del b 
        print(b)  # NameError: name 'b' is not defined
    except NameError as e:
        b = 'default'
    print(b) # default
```